# write a function () that returns the count of all elements and arrays including nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

using recursion and the ternary operator . I will be very grateful if you explain how it is arranged.`

```
 console.log (deepCount([]));
0
 console.log (deepCount([1 ,2 ,3]));
3
 console.log (deepCount(["x", "z", ["y"]]));
4
 console.log (deepCount([1, 2,[3, 4,[5]]]));
7
 console.log (deepCount([[[[]]]]));
3
```

```
let arr = [1, 2, [3, 4[5]]];

function deepCount(arr) {
  let result = arr.length;
  for (const char of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[char])) {
      result += arr[char];
      deepCount(arr);
    }
    return result;
  };
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` in the function.

Comment: The recursion should be on the array element, not the whole array. And you have to use the result: `result += deepCount(arr[ch])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked: using **recursion** and a **ternary operator** :

For my part (in addition to the remarks made by **Barmar**), your first error is to not have indent your code : it's a simple way to check the parity of your braces. I recommend the [Whitesmiths style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style), of course.

K&R and other styles with "Egyptian braces" are unsuitable for this check...

```js
console.log( deepCount( []                ));     // --> 0
console.log( deepCount( [1 ,2 ,3]         ));    // --> 3
console.log( deepCount( ["x", "z", ["y"]] ));   // --> 4
console.log( deepCount( [1, 2,[3, 4,[5]]] ));  // --> 7
console.log( deepCount( [[[[]]]]          )); // --> 3   

function deepCount( arr )
  {
  let count = arr.length;
  for (const elm of arr) 
    {
    count += Array.isArray(elm) ? deepCount(elm) : 0;
    }
  return count;
  }
```

> The same, in a "single" line of code:

```js
const deepCount = arr =>
  arr.reduce((N,x)=>N+=(Array.isArray(x)?deepCount(x):0),arr.length);

console.log( deepCount( []                ));     // --> 0
console.log( deepCount( [1 ,2 ,3]         ));    // --> 3
console.log( deepCount( ["x", "z", ["y"]] ));   // --> 4
console.log( deepCount( [1, 2,[3, 4,[5]]] ));  // --> 7
console.log( deepCount( [[[[]]]]          )); // --> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use `for-of`, the iteration variable is the array element, not its index. So you should use `char`, not `arr[char]`. I've renamed `char` to `element`, since it has nothing to do with characters.
2. You need to add the value returned from the recursive call to `result`, not add the array element to it.
3. `return result` should not be inside the loop, it should be at the end.

```js
function deepCount(arr) {
  let result = arr.length;
  for (const element of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      result += deepCount(element);
    }
  };
  return result;
}

console.log(deepCount([]));
console.log(deepCount([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(deepCount(["x", "z", ["y"]]));
console.log(deepCount([1, 2, [3, 4, [5]]]));
console.log (deepCount([[[[]]]]));
```